# Cant find method: Using MVC httppost to add rows to azure table storage

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, asp.net-mvc-5, azure-table-storage

I am trying to add a row to an azure table storage. It is my first time working with this so I followed an MS tutorial, unfortunately they use console app and not MVC, so I had to improvise a bit, Basically, when adding an `[httpPost]` to my `AddRow` method I get a http 404 error *"Server Error in '/' Application.The resource cannot be found. "*

Code (inside HomeController):

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult AddRow()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Your application description page.";

            try
            {
                CloudStorageAccount cloudStorageAcc = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("StorageConnectionString"));

                CloudTableClient cloudTableClient = cloudStorageAcc.CreateCloudTableClient();

                CloudTable table = cloudTableClient.GetTableReference("Users");
                table.CreateIfNotExists();

                Insert inserter1 = new Insert("Bob", "Contoso");
                inserter1.UserName = "Bobbie";

                TableOperation insertOperation = TableOperation.Insert(inserter1);

                table.Execute(insertOperation);
            }
            catch
            {
                return View();
            }

            return View();
        }
```

I try to access this by **mysite.azurewebsites.net/Home/AddRow**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When we make a request in browser, the default HttpMethod is HttpGet. It doesn’t  match defined HttpMethod (Httppost) in function. So, it will return above error. We usually use post method to summit form data, then we can define the httpMethod in the view page.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("AddRow", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
   // data or logic
}
```

We also can use code or tools (postman,fidder) to call the function with defined HttpMethod.

It seems that you set same value to the [**partitionkey** and **rowkey**] for every http request. If it is that, it just can work correctly for the first time. Because [**partitionkey** and **rowkey**] is the unique for the tableEntity(record). More detail please refer to the [document](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-tables/#add-an-entity-to-a-table).